# Can enemy ships have Augments?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When flying the Zoltan ship, if you get an event with boarders it sometimes justifies bypassing your Super Shields by saying "they must have a Zoltan Shield Bypass installed on their ship!"

Which makes me wonder, is this just a flavour text excuse to justify an otherwise contradictory encounter, or can enemy ships actually have Augments? If the latter, which ships can have which augments?

Comment: "I never asked for this" - My ship after being heavily augmented.

Comment: @Zibbobz That's kinda what my ship would've said just now when fighting the Rebel Flagship, and I had four Zoltan and the Battery active for a total of 33 power in systems!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes they can have augments.  The only ones I've encountered are:

- Zoltan shields (obviously)
- Rock Plating (most rock ships have this)
- Engi Medi-bot Dispersal (I've ran into several torus class ships with this augment).

I've run the medi-bot augment several times where their crew was healing while outside of their med-bay, which implies that they have that particular augmentation.

I have not encountered any ship with zoltan shield bypass yet, but I do not play the zoltan cruiser that often to know for sure.

Comment: Doh! You are correct about the Rock of course.  I'll edit my answer but yours deserves credit.

Comment: I reguarly encounter slug ships with regenerating hulls.

Comment: Can anyone determine if the Mantis ships have pheromones? (+25% movement speed)

Answer (score 5):

It is a flavor text only. It is worth noting that bypassing the Zoltan shield augment only exists in the AE, but that flavor text is in both standard mode and AE. See z-'s answer for remaining details.

Comment: I have a vague memory of a slug ship's hull breach repairing itself.  However, I think I dreamed that.

Comment: See that's the thing, I'm fairly sure I've seen Slug breach healing, and I think I even saw the healing nanobots effect on an Engi ship...

Comment: This deserves investigation... if they do exist it is only the "racial" augments that exist.